# Leaflet edit GeoJson Data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, leaflet.draw, min.js

I made a code below for creating shapes with some informations. I can edit thoose informations until my map is open. But after update geojson by ***"Export features to local file"*** and page reload, shapes remain unclickable and to correct the informations I have to delete some shapes and recreate them with proper parameters.

**Question:**

Is it possible to edit the shape's data each time I just open my page? Like I can edit the shapes itself by ***"Edit layers"*** button?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
        
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="crossorigin=""/>
   
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
   

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" integrity="sha256-it5nQKHTz+34HijZJQkpNBIHsjpV8b6QzMJs9tmOBSo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       
       
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #mapid { height: 100% }
    </style> 
    
  <!--Add draw plugin -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    </script>
    
 <!--Load plugin -->    

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>   


    <style>
   
      #export{
            position: absolute;
            top:600px;
            //right:1800px;
            z-index:1000;
            background:white;
            color:black;
            padding:6px;
            border-radius:4px;
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size:12px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
    
        #export {
            top:370px;
        }
        

    </style>
    </head>  
    <body>
    
        <a href='#' id='export'>Export Features to local file</a>
    
        <div id="mapid"></div>
    
    <script> 

var features = "https://api.npoint.io/4fefc36933cc5c22cee4";    
    
      var cities = L.layerGroup();




    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

    var streets   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr}),
        sat  = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}),
OSM = L.tileLayer('https://maps.jakdojade.pl/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

Topo = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');






    var map = L.map('mapid', {
        center: [49.9225,18.99195],
        //drawControl: true,
        zoom: 8,
        layers: [streets, cities]
        
    });
    

    var baseLayers = {
    

            "Podstawowa": streets,
        "Satelitarna": sat,
        "OSM": OSM,
        "Topo": Topo,
        
    };
//SVG2


//SVG2

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, {collapsed:false, position:'topleft'}).addTo(map);
    

    
</script> 




  <script>
  


  
var featureGroup = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(features, {
             
       
}).addTo(map);


        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            edit: {
                featureGroup: featureGroup,
                
            }
        }).addTo(map); 
        

map.on('draw:created', function (event) {


    var layer = event.layer,
        feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};
    
    feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
   
    featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
    addPopup(layer);
    
});

var openLayer;

function addPopup(layer){
 
  let popupContent = 
  '<form>' + 
  'Link:<br><input type="text" id="input_link"><br>' +
  'Cena:<br><input type="text" id="input_cena"><br>' +
  'Area:<br><input type="text" id="input_area"><br>' +
  'Image:<br><input type="text" id="input_image"><br>' +
  '</form>';  
  

 
  layer.on("popupopen", function (e) {
    var _layer = e.popup._source;
    if(!_layer.feature){
        _layer.feature = {
        properties: {}
      };
      
      
    }
    
    document.getElementById("input_link").value = _layer.feature.properties.link || "";
    document.getElementById("input_cena").value = _layer.feature.properties.cena || "";
    document.getElementById("input_area").value = _layer.feature.properties.area || "";
    document.getElementById("input_image").value = _layer.feature.properties.image || "";
    document.getElementById("input_link").focus();
    openLayer = _layer;
    
  });
  
  layer.on("popupclose", function (e) {
    openLayer = undefined;
 });
 
 layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup(); 

        
};

L.DomEvent.on(document,"keyup",function(){
  if(openLayer){
    link = document.getElementById("input_link").value;
    cena = document.getElementById("input_cena").value;
    area = document.getElementById("input_area").value;
    image = document.getElementById("input_image").value;

    openLayer.feature.properties.link = link;
    openLayer.feature.properties.cena = cena; 
    openLayer.feature.properties.area = area;
    openLayer.feature.properties.image = image;
    openLayer.feature.properties.N = 1;
    
    
  }
 
   
})
  



        document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
            // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
            var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();

            // Stringify the GeoJson
            var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

            // Create export
            document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
            document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','sl.geojson');
        };
        

    </script>

      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, but you can edit now. You just have to wait a while as the layers have a lot of dots and it takes a while, but editing is possible.

Comment: But I mean to edit informations I add to the layers, not just geometry itself.

Comment: The plugin's documentation has not been read :) `var featureGroup = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX (features, {}). AddTo (map);` In this empty object you can insert: `onEachFeature: YourDataChangingFunction` 
And in this function, you can view layer data. See documentation [geojson](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson)
And it's best to remove that old `L.Geojson.ajax` plugin and replace it with `Fetch` or `axios` or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I did it quickly, so you have to adapt to your own code.
I removed L.GeoJSON.AJAX but nothing prevents you from continuing to use it, I advise you not to ;)

```js
var features = "https://api.npoint.io/4fefc36933cc5c22cee4";

var cities = L.layerGroup();

var mbAttr =
  'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
  '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
  'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  mbUrl =
  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw";

var streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
  id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  attribution: mbAttr,
});

var map = L.map("mapid", {
  center: [49.9225, 18.99195],
  zoom: 8,
});

streets.addTo(map);

// add layers to map

async function fetchData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

fetchData(features).then((geoJsonData) => {
  const feature = L.geoJSON(geoJsonData, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.on("mouseover", function(e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
          color: "red",
          weight: 2,
        });
      });
      layer.on("mouseout", function(e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
          color: "#3388ff",
          weight: 2,
        });
      });
      addPopup(layer);
    },
  }).addTo(map);
});

// --------------------------------------------------
// draw section

let drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

map.addControl(
  new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItems,
      poly: {
        allowIntersection: false,
      },
    },
    draw: {
      polygon: {
        allowIntersection: false,
        showArea: true,
      },
    },
  })
);

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(event) {
  let layer = event.layer;
  let feature = (layer.feature = layer.feature || {});
  let type = event.layerType;

  feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
  let props = (feature.properties = feature.properties || {});

  props.type = type;

  if (type === "circle") {
    props.radius = layer.getRadius();
  }

  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
  addPopup(layer);
});

var openLayer;

function addPopup(layer) {
  let popupContent = `
    <form>Link:<br>
    <input type="text" id="input_link" value="${
      layer.feature.properties.link || ""
    }"><br>
    Cena:<br><input type="text" id="input_cena" value=${
      layer.feature.properties.cena || ""
    }><br>
    Area:<br><input type="text" id="input_area" value=${
      layer.feature.properties.area || ""
    }><br>
    Image:<br><input type="text" id="input_image" value=${
      layer.feature.properties.image || ""
    }><br>
    </form>`;

  layer.on("popupopen", function(e) {
    var _layer = e.popup._source;
    if (!_layer.feature) {
      _layer.feature = {
        properties: {},
      };
    }

    //   document.getElementById("input_link").value =
    //     _layer.feature.properties.link || "";
    //   document.getElementById("input_cena").value =
    //     _layer.feature.properties.cena || "";
    //   document.getElementById("input_area").value =
    //     _layer.feature.properties.area || "";
    //   document.getElementById("input_image").value =
    //     _layer.feature.properties.image || "";
    //   document.getElementById("input_link").focus();
    //   openLayer = _layer;
  });

  layer.on("popupclose", function(e) {
    openLayer = undefined;
  });

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();
}

L.DomEvent.on(document, "keyup", function() {
  if (openLayer) {
    link = document.getElementById("input_link").value;
    cena = document.getElementById("input_cena").value;
    area = document.getElementById("input_area").value;
    image = document.getElementById("input_image").value;

    openLayer.feature.properties.link = link;
    openLayer.feature.properties.cena = cena;
    openLayer.feature.properties.area = area;
    openLayer.feature.properties.image = image;
    openLayer.feature.properties.N = 1;
  }
});

document.getElementById("export").onclick = function(e) {
  // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
  var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();

  // Stringify the GeoJson
  var convertedData =
    "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

  // Create export
  document
    .getElementById("export")
    .setAttribute("href", "data:" + convertedData);
  document.getElementById("export").setAttribute("download", "sl.geojson");
};
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#mapid {
  height: 100%
}

#export {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#export {
  top: 370px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='export'>Export Features to local file</a>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

You can add the option to modify fields (form) only when you click the edit button.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.EDITED, function (event) {
  let layers = event.layers;

  layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    addPopup(layer);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code - looks amazing. But values in popups are not saved.

Comment: Well, without exaggeration, I will not do the entire project for you :) Add a save button in the popup under the input fields. Clicking on the save button will change the data in the given layer. You can download the data using [new FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and that's it, then the data export button will download all the modified data.

Comment: I'll try, thank you :)

Comment: Here you have my solution, of course, no form and no saving, but you can easily add it - [create-and-save-geojson](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#53.create-and-save-geojson)

Comment: Great, useful website - thank you Grzegorz